# Minimal Permissions for Packer remote VMware-iso builder

Tags: vmware, packer

I'm trying to use Packer to build images from iso on a remote VMware cluster, and there are security concerns with allowing direct access to the host. What are the minimal permissions required for an account on the esxi host to successfully complete the build?

Answer (score 1):

The user needs to be able to run the following commands:

1. `vmkfstools`
2. `vim-cmd`
3. `test`
4. `sh`
5. `ls`
6. `rm`
7. `esxcli`
8. `stat`
9. `mkdir`
10. `shaXsum`
11. `md5sum`

For `vim-cmd` it must be allowed to run:

1. `vmsvc/power.getstate`
2. `vmsvc/reload`
3. `vmsvc/power.on`
4. `vmsvc/power.off`
5. `solo/registervm`
6. `vmsvc/unregister`
7. `vmsvc/destroy`
8. `vmsvc/tools.install`

And for `esxcli`:

1. `network ip connection list`
2. `network vm list`
3. `network vm port list`
4. `system version get`
5. `system settings advanced list -o /Net/GuestIPHack`

If security is I high concern I would recommend to look into running a dedicated ESXi host for Packer builds or use *nested virtualisation* to run a ESXi on top of vSphere just as a build host.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rickard, we independently discovered the nested virtualization route and I think that's what we'll be doing. Hopefully this thread can help others with similar concerns get there quicker.